# How can one explain simultaneously different temperatures in the trunk of a human body?

Tags: body-temperature, biochemistry

According to researches done on frostbite, the temperature within the human body-core is supposed to always be uniform throughout. But is this assumption accurate? Could there be a movement of heat from the less essential organs to the more essential organs in the human body-torso, at times of need?

Thus, in freezing conditions isn't the bum the least essential organ of the body-core, and of the whole body as well, for that matter? And still core-temperature is measured rectally.

Reading in a story on the net about a man in Alaska who had to walk home in sub-zero temperature, after experiencing a punctured bicycle-tire. When he got home he noticed that his bum was suffering frostbite. Which made me wonder if he was wearing too thin trousers, or if heat had been borrowed from his bum to support his essential inner organs? Or, maybe a combination of the both? Put differently; Is this story trustworthy? Is it really possible for just one part of the torso to freeze? And if so, by what function, or functions, can this happen?

[Link to story by Christopher Buehler](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-things-that-people-who-live-in-places-with-brutally-low-temperatures-know-that-the-rest-of-us-dont) (Third story down)

Comment: This is trivially answered with a simple web search, or by going out on a cold day and noticing that your fingers get cold before you do. I don't know what the anus has to do with your question.

Comment: @Carey Gregory. Please read my edited question.

Comment: Your edits didn't help. You're asking a high school first aid question that can be answered by google. The short answer is no, the temperature of your body is not the same everywhere.

Comment: Note, that I am not asking if the temperature of the body is the same everywhere, but if the temperature of the trunk of the body is the same everywhere within the trunk? There is a big difference between the two.

Comment: Then explain why you're asking about the temperature of the anus. Your question lacks prior research and it's just plain bizarre.

Comment: But, isn't that self explanatory. Isn't the classic way of measuring body temperature to assert a thermometer into the anus? And that most, if not all, experiments measure core temperature that way?

Comment: Okay, so you're not asking about the temperature of the anus, you're asking about rectal temperature. Yes, I believe rectal temperature is generally accepted as a good measure of core temperature. So that leads us to what are you asking? Is core core temp the same as core temp?

Comment: Yes, core temp = core temp. But I don't understand what you're actually asking. You seem to be fluent in English so language doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Gonna agree with Carey here...I don't see a lot of good faith effort. Maybe look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and see if your thought pattern qualifies: it seems like you might be wondering about one thing but asking about another because you hope it answers your initial query. Might be best to start from where you are actually coming from.